# How to display Magento cart button on blank page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, customer-account, header

Magento has a default bar that has two buttons: Account and Cart. I would like to display this bar on my homepage which has a blank layout but I can't figure out how to do this. I came across this code snippet:

```
Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart')
```

I am unsure of whether this is the code I need, or if there is a better way to do it. I'm new to Magento and not yet comfortable with using it. Should I be trying to do this from Magento CMS or somewhere in the backend?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: your homepage is a cms page or any other?

Comment: Yes it is a CMS page that follows the blank layout. I added some content to the homepage but I want to include the default shopping cart BUTTON in the header of the homepage. Any ideas? Is it better to do it programatically?

Comment: In that cms page design section, check which layout you have been selected

Comment: The layout selected is "Empty".

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 2):

To show Account and Cart in empty layout,make the changes in below file,

```
app\design\frontend\package\theme\template\page\empty.phtml
```

Add the below line,

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
```

after,

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
```

Comment: Great answer! How can I show the account and cart without the rest of the header? I don't want to display the logo, search bar. I just want the Cart, and Account buttons to show on the homepage. Thanks in advance.